# .NET Core 3.1/React Template - REST API Class - Ignore Property in JSON result

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, react-redux

I have a project on **C# Core 3.1** with **React** and **Redux** template with **EF Core** for DB. I need to exclude Id from the DTO class which I send via **REST API** Controller.

I need to use Id for load-related class vie EF Core, but I do not show in REST API result:

```
{
    "id": 1, -- DISABLE to show
    "product": "TEST1"
}
```

**C# Class:**

```
public class ProductResDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // DISABLE to show in REST API result
    public string Product{ get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    // GET api/<ProductController>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ProductReqDto model)
    {
        try
        {
            var product = await _context.Products
                .OrderBy(b => b.Name)
                .Where(w => w.Name == model.Name)
            .Select(c => new ProductResDto
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Product = c.Name                    
            }).FirstAsync();

            // Grades
            product.Grades = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

            // Description
            product.Descriptions = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

            // Files
            product.Files = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

            // Parameters
            product.Parameters = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

            return Ok(product);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Is there any chance to this parameter disable for REST API result or load in `await _context.Products` using by `.Select()`

2 objects: One for ID only and one for `ProductResDto`

Thank you

Comment: Before send Dto to Client set It's value to Zero.

Comment: Do you need to exclude that property from JSON response? If so, you could use [JsonIgnore] attribute.

Comment: Set DTO Property do Zero or Null is not right solution. Only JsonIgnor is located in NewtonJson lib, but it is not wok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your class as following

```
public class ProductResDto
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I must install some Nuget Package? Because VS do not recognize Json, only JsonIgnore reference is in NewtonJson lib

Comment: I must install Nuget package [System.Text.Json.Serialization] and after that works fine and I do not see Id property, THX

Comment: default ASP.NET Core template already uses `System.Text.Json` by default

Answer (score 0):

I see different solutions:

1. Using
   [`JsonIgnoreAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1)
   on  `Id` property like this:

   ```
   using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

   public class ProductResDto
   {
       [JsonIgnore]
       public int Id { get; set; } 
       public string Product { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create `Contract`-layer for your application that will contain all
   the `OutCountract` models. So your Contract model will not contain
   `Id` property:

   ```
   public class ProductResOutContract
   {
       public string Product { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And utilize it like:

   ```
   // GET api/<ProductController>
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ProductReqDto model)
   {
       try
       {
           var product = await _context.Products
               .OrderBy(b => b.Name)
               .Where(w => w.Name == model.Name)
           .Select(c => new ProductResDto
           {
               Id = c.Id,
               Product = c.Name                    
           }).FirstAsync();

           // Grades
           product.Grades = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

           // Description
           product.Descriptions = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

           // Files
           product.Files = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

           // Parameters
           product.Parameters = ''; // LOAD ADD. INFO (use product.Id like FK in DB)

           var productOutContract = ConvertToOutCountract(product);

           return Ok(productOutContract);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           return NotFound();
       }
   }

   private static ProductReqOutContract ConvertToOutCountract(ProductReqDto product)
   {
       var outCountract = new ProductOutContract
       {
           // Fill the properties;
       };

       return outCountract;
   }
   ```
3. Returning Id is also not bad. You should just handle the model on
   the frontend properly.

I prefer the 2nd or the 3rd solution. It's more clear when the API-layer and data-layer are separate.